# R: Counting points on a grid of rectangles:

Tags: r

I have a grid of rectangles, whose coordinates are stored in the variable say, 'gridPoints' as shown below:

```
gridData.Grid=GridTopology(c(min(data$LATITUDE),min(data$LONGITUDE)),c(0.005,0.005),c(32,32));

gridPoints = as.data.frame(coordinates(gridData.Grid))[1:1000,];

names(gridPoints) = c("LATITUDE","LONGITUDE");
plot(gridPoints,col=4);
points(data,col=2);
```

When plotted, these are the black points in the image,[image]

Now, I have another data set of points called say , 'data', which when plotted are the blue points above.

I would want a count of how many blue points fall within each rectangle in the grid. Each rectangle can be represented by the center of the rectangle, along with the corresponding count of blue points within it in the output. Also, if the blue point lies on any of the sides of the rectangle, it can be considered as lying within the rectangle while making the count. The plot has the blue and black points looking like circles, but they are just standard points/coordinates and hence, much smaller than the circles. In a special case, the rectangle can also be a square.

Comment: Since you know the `x` and `y` coordinates of your "blue points" why not just bin them by the coordinates of your defined squares?

Comment: That would be a start but note that, I have the coordinates in a data.frame, that needs to be traversed correctly as well. I 'do not' have an indicator/id/factor denoting a square number for each coordinate in the input data frame of gridPoints. Also, I wonder if there are faster/ more efficient ways to do this as well? Would like to see a complete solution in R as the answer, that I could test out end to end as well.

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

```
x <- seq(0,10,by=2)
y <- seq(0, 30, by=10)
grid <- expand.grid(x, y)
N <- 100
points <- cbind(runif(N, 0, 10), runif(N, 0, 30))

plot(grid, t="n", xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
points(points, col="blue", pch="+") 
abline(v=x, h=y)

binxy <- data.frame(x=findInterval(points[,1], x),
                    y=findInterval(points[,2], y))

(results <- table(binxy))
d <- as.data.frame.table(results)
xx <- x[-length(x)] + 0.5*diff(x)
d$x <- xx[d$x]
yy <- y[-length(y)] + 0.5*diff(y)
d$y <- yy[d$y]
with(d, text(x, y, label=Freq))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A more general approach (may be overkill for this case, but if you generalize to arbitrary polygons it will still work) is to use the `over` function in the sp package.  This will find which polygon each point is contained in (then you can count them up).

You will need to do some conversions up front (to spatial objects) but this method will work with more complicated polygons than rectangles.

If all the rectangles are exactly the same size, then you could use k nearest neighbor techniques using the centers of the rectangles, see the `knn` and `knn1` functions in the class package.

Comment: it depends what generalisation would be required, can spatial data consider 3D?

Comment: @baptiste, I don't think that the current implementation in sp would do 3d, but knn would still work if the polyhedrons fit the correct space (squares or rectangular prisms extended from the original would work).